# Is it possible to define AngularJS route's templateUrl path fully agnostic to IIS app folder structure?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, iis, routes

I have have done some research here and in general, but couldnt find a proper way to implement this.

We have and MVC/WebAPI2/AngularJS Web app.

I am trying to achive this goal: being able to put my app anywhere in IIS app folder structure without any code changes. That means, get rid of any IIS Application name in my code.

Here is a simple fragment of ng-route path defined:

> .when("/", { templateUrl: "Home/Main", controller: "MainController",
>   controllerAs: "vm" })

Now, the IIS app is called **ReportsWeb** (but could be any name)

If I set **ReportsWeb** app under **Default Web Site** root:

> http://localhost/ReportsWeb/

then everything works fine, and templateUrl page is loaded fine.

But if the app is placed under another IIS App (the one we have here is called **RealSuiteApps**, which is itself under **Default Web Site**)

> http://localhost/RealSuiteApps/ReportsWeb/

then, the templates are not loaded, **since constructed URL for templateUrl is no longer valid**:

```
http://localhost/RealSuiteApps/Home/Main
```

If I change templateUrl to "/Home/Main", constructed URL is not valid again

```
http://localhost/Home/Main
```

If I change templateUrl to "./Home/Main", constructed URL is not valid again

```
http://localhost/RealSuiteApps/Home/Main
```

Is it possible to define templateUrl **only relative to the latest App name in the IIS hierarchy without hardcoding all these names**, so that it will work in any IIS app tree

> http://localhost/App1/App2/App3/ReportsWeb/

Thanks!

Comment: can store a constant for something like `appPath` and use that to concatenate with template file names

Comment: charlietfl, the point is that I dont want to hardcode any names, I want path to be fully relative

Comment: browser needs to know what path is.... it can't guess. By using a constant you only set it once. Could use build tools to set that value automatically based on development directory

Comment: charlietfl, seems so ))

Comment: You can use a build tool like html2js and it won't matter where your templates are at runtime. You can specify a module name like `templates/` which is purely cosmetic.

Comment: thank you, I will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

I use `grunt-html2js` tool to convert all html templates to Javascript at build time, which uses Angular's template cache.

I've defined my grunt task to overwrite the default module naming to `templates/` so that I can reference any template easily:

```
html2js: {
      options: {
        rename: function (moduleName) {
          return moduleName.replace(/^.*[\/\\]/, 'templates/');
        }
      },
      all: {
        src: ['./src/**/*.html', '!./src/index.html'],
        dest: 'tmp/templates.js'
      }

    },
```

This will create a `templates.js` file that I can include as a script tag. Then I can access any template like so:

```
templatUrl: 'templates/my-template-filename.html'
```

Regardless of where it's path was in the source code.